# Why Onload javascript functions working slower than expected?

Tags: javascript, css

```
         <body onload="checknorecords('<%= request.getAttribute("CHK")%>')">
             function checknorecords(obj)
               {

                if(obj!=null&&obj=="nopo")
                      {
               alert("No PO Records found for given details");
               }
                  if(obj!=null&&obj=="norpln")
             {
    alert("No RPLN Records found for given details");
         }
}
```

It takes more than 30 minutes , I have JSP page, have called more than one function in onload with getAttribute also.so all the pages are working dead slow of those function.may i use jquery instead of this.Please tell me the way to resolve this problem.thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

onLoad fires after every asset is completely loaded on the page. That means all JavaScripts, CSS and Image. If you have a lot of images on the page, it might take a while for them to load. You might want to consider using onDomReady instead of onLoad. However, having a page that takes 30 seconds to load is sort of ridiculous. So I suggest you read up on web performance optimization.

Comment: I would add that if your page took that long, many of your punters would just give up. About 5 seconds is as much as most people will tolerate.